# Discord.js: Embed not sending

Tags: javascript, discord.js, referenceerror

I'm trying to make a help embed command with reactions, but I keep getting this error
I'm trying to make a help embed with reactions, but when I do !help, it doesnt send the embed???

I'm trying to make a help embed command with reactions, but I keep getting this error I'm trying to make a help embed with reactions, but when I do !help, it doesnt send the embed???

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "Help command",
    execute(message, args){
        async function helpEmbed(message, args) { 
            const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Help!')
                .setDescription(`**React with one of the circles to get help with a category!**`)
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Moderation', value: ':blue_circle:'},
                    { name: 'Fun', value: ':green_circle:'},
                    { name: 'Misc', value: ':purple_circle:'},
                )
                .setColor(4627199)
            message.channel.send({embed: helpEmbed}).then(embedMessage => {
                embedMessage.react('')
                embedMessage.react('')
                embedMessage.react('')
            })
            const msg = await sendReact()
            const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
            const filter = (reaction, user) =>{
                return ['', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            }
            
            msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();

            if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                try {
                    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
                        reaction.users.remove(userId)
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.')
                }

                message.channel.send('Moderation');
            } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                try {
                    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
                        reaction.users.remove(userId)
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.')
                }
                message.channel.send('Fun');
            } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                try {
                    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
                        reaction.users.remove(userId)
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.')
                }
                message.channel.send('Misc')
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
        });
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help but try on line 6 where it says "execute()". Try "execute: function()" without the quotes

Comment: @MsonC It fixes the errors, but it doesn't send the embed

Comment: @MsonC it doesnt do anything, the errors are gone, but the embed doesn't send

Comment: Please try to set ";" behind .setColor(4627199)

Comment: @GillesHeinesch still doesn't work

Comment: @math1337 I tried your code and it sends the embed just fine. I only received an error because it tells me I have no `sendReact` function that it can call upon on. Is that what you were referencing? 

I did change the indenting, but that shouldn't change how the code acts, merely how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You defined helpEmbed funcion but not called it.

try writing "helpEmbed()" after "execute(message, args){"

if still doesn't work:
Check bot's permission
Bot needs *SEND_EMBED_LINKS* Permission in that channel.